# Linux Interrupt Handling

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I am trying to understand the Linux interrupt handling mechanism. I tried googling a bit but couldn't find an answer to this one. Can someone please explain it to me why the handle_IRQ_event needs to call  local_irq_disable at the end? After this the control goes back to do_irq which eventually will go back to the entry point. Then who will enable the interrupts back.? It is the responsibility of the interrupt handler? If so why is that so?

## Edit

Code for reference

```
asmlinkage int handle_IRQ_event(unsigned int irq, struct pt_regs *regs, struct irqaction *action) 
{ 
    int status = 1; 
    int retval = 0; 

    if (!(action->flags & SA_INTERRUPT)) 
        local_irq_enable(); 
    do 
    { 
       status |= action->flags; 
       retval |= action->handler(irq, action->dev_id, regs); 
       action = action->next; 
    } 
    while (action); 

    if (status & SA_SAMPLE_RANDOM) 
        add_interrupt_randomness(irq);

    local_irq_disable(); 

    return retval; 
}
```

Comment: Is there any relevant code you can post? What you've been looking at? Without any context, we can't help you.

Comment: Antiduh, I was referring to the use of local_irq_disable call towards the end in the handle_IRQ_event function.?

Comment: I know. Post some code in your question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: asmlinkage int handle_IRQ_event(unsigned int irq, struct pt_regs *regs,
                                struct irqaction *action)
{
        int status = 1;
        int retval = 0;

        if (!(action->flags & SA_INTERRUPT))
                local_irq_enable();

        do {
                status |= action->flags;
                retval |= action->handler(irq, action->dev_id, regs);
                action = action->next;
        } while (action);

        if (status & SA_SAMPLE_RANDOM)
                add_interrupt_randomness(irq);

        local_irq_disable();

        return retval;
}

Comment: Above is the implementation of handle_IRQ_event function from LLD3. Please let me know if this is sufficient?

Comment: Can you specify kernel version ( or better provide link )? I can't find such code not in 2.* ( http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86_64/kernel/irq.c?v=2.4.37#L463 ), nor in 3.* or 4.* ( http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/irq/handle.c?v=4.4#L135 )

Answer (score 2):

The version of `handle_IRQ_event` from LDD3 appears to come from the 2.6.8 kernel, or possibly earlier. Assuming we're dealing with x86, the processor clears the interrupt flag (IF) in the EFLAGS register before it calls the interrupt handler. The old EFLAGS register will be restored by the `iret` instruction.

Linux's `SA_INTERRUPT` IRQ handler flag (now obsolete) determines whether higher priority interrupts are allowed in the interrupt handler. The `SA_INTERRUPT` flag is set for "fast" interrupt handlers that left interrupts disabled. The `SA_INTERRUPT` flag is not set for "slow" interrupt handlers that re-enable interrupts.

Regardless of the `SA_INTERRUPT` flag, `do_IRQ` itself runs with interrupts disabled and they are still disabled when `handle_IRQ_event` is called.  Since `handle_IRQ_event` can enable interrupts, the call to `local_irq_disable` at the end ensures they are disabled again on return to `do_IRQ`.

The relevant source code files in the 2.6.8 kernel for i386 architecture are `arch/i386/kernel/entry.S`, and `arch/i386/kernel/irq.c`.

Comment: Ian, Thanks for the explanation.